# Change button color after updating text field

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

There are 20 `JTextField` and one calculate button in panel.
after entering data to text field and I click button,  program calculate as well.

What I want to do, after first click for button, is there any updates in any text fields,  button colors should be change as green (it means you have to know something already change and you have to calculate again).

How can I proceed with that, should I put action listener for each text field or any other short code exist?

Comment: First you need to write some code

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. As far my concern to yr question you can track button click event and put code there for check jtextfield value and on the bases of value you can take decision to change the color of the button